# Websphere 8.0.0.10 - EntityManager not injected (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, websphere, openjpa

In our application we are using 2 databases in 2 modules each with its own persistence.xml:

persistence.xml for first :

```
<persistence-unit name="first-databasePU">

<mapping-file>META-INF/dynamic_orm.xml</mapping-file>

<class>some.class.using.first.ASDF</class>
....
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="100" />
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
</properties>
```

and similar for second :

```
<persistence-unit name="second-databasePU">

<mapping-file>META-INF/dynamic_orm.xml</mapping-file>

<class>some.class.using.second.ASDF</class>
....
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
  <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
  <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="100" />
  <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
</properties>
```

Example class of DAOBean :

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class ASDF {
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="first-databasePU")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        entityManager = em;
    }

    public void someFunction() {
        entityManager.something();
    }
}
```

Normally our EntityManagers are initialized correctly. But set upped on Websphere calling method someFunction() is giving us NullPointerException.

Did some digging and found [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cspr_data_access.html)

But after adding to our web.xml :

```
<persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>some/name/first</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>first-databasePU</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>

<persistence-context-ref>
    <persistence-context-ref-name>some/name/second</persistence-context-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>second-databasePU</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-context-ref>
```

nothing has changed, so next i tried to pull EntityManager directly from JNDI like in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/usclient005.htm), but it also failed.

So right now i am searching for any idea why it could not work.

Additional info:
Our Websphere is configured as docker image using jthon scripts and wsadmin.sh.
Both DataSources are set upped. And application config can see them.

Comment: You have hibernate properties in your persistence.xml but tagged the question as openJpa.  What are you really using?  Turn logging on and check the logs during deployment for warnings or errors loading the persistence unit.

Comment: As far as i understood Websphere is using OpenJPA as implementation, this one is just something i pulled from our config. Because we are having the same config for different profiles

Comment: You mention both datasources are setup, but haven't shown any configuration in JPA that would tell it what datasource to use.  My guess is that you are converting from Spring JPA and have been using it to configure your persistence unit, and now are using websphere and missed some of your configuration.  Turn on logging and it should show you any problems it is encountering.